# MDX Distinct Count on dim attribute

Tags: mdx

I m by no stretch of the imagination an MDX developer.
I have an EPM cube with 3 dimension. resource, project, date.
project has a catgory attribute.

i am trying to create a calculation that counts the number of resources in a particular category.

The calc I did
DISTINCTCOUNT([Dim Resource].[Resource UID])

but its not sub totaling by category[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBO1Z.jpg).
how can i achieve this?
thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Try adding EXISTING after the first bracket.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the DISTINCTCOUNT function is what you want as I believe it will evaluate a measure value then count the distinct non empty values. Try this instead:

```
Count(Existing [Dim Resource].[Resource UID].[Resource UID].Members)
```

Existing should help it limit to the resources in your current context. Count should be adequate since a dimension attribute is already a set of distinct Resource UIDs. And I mentioned Resource UID twice to ensure we don't count the "All" member.